# How to retrieve blocked mail item from Gmail

Tags: gmail

A business associate sent an email to me containing an attachment.  The Gmail team deemed this attachment dangerous, and did not load it into my Gmail inbox.

> The message "RE: Subject" from {name} {email_address} contained a virus or a suspicious attachment. It was therefore not fetched from your account {my_account} and has been left on the server.

I have searched and only found advice relating to blocked email addresses.  This is not my issue.

How can I get Gmail to download this email to my Gmail inbox from my mail server?  How can I tell Gmail this email and attachment are okay and can be trusted?

Comment: The file was already filtered before it reached your inbox.  You will have to have the business associate send you the file another way.

Comment: @Ramhound - In theory I could do that, but he is travelling and won't have ability to re-send for days.  I need the email and attachment today.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  Google filtered the file before it got to you.  There is no way to recover the file.

Comment: @Ramhound - I hope that's not the case!  GMail should not permanently block legitimate email.

Comment: @AndroidAddict, since Gmail only fetches the emails from your own domain's server, don't you have access to your domains own email server?

Comment: Google didn't block the email.  Google blocked a file that was infected with a virus.  You can always go to your mail server and download the email directly from it.  The file on Google's servers does not exist nor did it ever exist because Google identified it as a virus.

Comment: @Ramhound Google DID block the email and the attachment is NOT INFECTED, plz see my post edit.  I can go to my web mail and do this, but I also want to archive the email in my Gmail folder system.  Not having it in my Gmail inbox is problematic.  `There should be an override when legitimate email is blocked in my opinion.`  I know the sender and trust them.

Comment: @AndroidAddict for now downloading it from your server should be good enough for you to have it. For the purpose of having it archived in Gmail, you can reply to the message (from google about the blocked mail) and then if the sender will send it again (when he returns from his travels) and it should go through.

Comment: Related: [Prevent Gmail telling me about an email that contains a virus or suspicious attachment?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87036/354)

Comment: From what I've seen, this only happens when you're doing POP3 fetching from a different server, hence the message about the message being left on the server.